# Querying AD for a service account's last authentication

Tags: active-directory

I have a list of service accounts that I'm not familiar with. I'm trying to find out the last time anything has authenticated with this account before I disable or remove it. Is there a way to do this in Active Directory?

Comment: which version of windows server are you running?

Comment: I'm on Server 2003

Comment: If the LastLogonTimeStamp is more than two weeks old, you can rely on that as the most recent logon. If an account logs on and the LastLogonTimeStamp is more than two weeks old, the domain controller replicates that attribute to other domain controllers within the usual time frame (within a site, right away; adjacent sites about 15 minutes).

Answer (score 4):

The closest you'll get is the "lastLogonTimestamp" on the object. To figure out where it's logging in from, you'll have to parse the Domain Controller Security event-logs to look for the login event and where it came from.

Comment: hopefully he's at the correct domain level since in earlier versions of AD lastlogintimestamp was not replicated.

Comment: In that case he'll have to check that value on every domain controller. It's work, but doable.

Comment: yep, just making sure he understood this.

Answer (score 2):

With Powershell you can put the list of users in a file called users.txt and try this:

```
    get-content d:\data\users.txt |get-aduser -properties lastlogontimestamp |foreach {
   $ll = Get-Date -Date ([DateTime]::FromFileTime([Int64]::Parse($_.lastlogontimestamp))) -Format MM/dd/yyyy
   write-host $_.name, $ll
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

And in case you're looking for other ways to query the lastLogonTimeStamp attribute, there is a command line tool called CSVDE (CSV Directory Export) that comes in handy.  The following command will output all Active Directory users and their attributes to a CSV file. The command has parameters that also lets you filter and choose specific attributes to export.

```
csvde -f Users.csv -r "(ObjectClass=User)"
```